# YouTube API - Get All Videos From User limits?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, youtube-api

I'm trying to get all the videos from one user via YouTube's data API. However, I've run into a roadblock: it doesn't seem to be returning all the videos from a user. Is there a way to raise the maximum amount that is shown?
The URL I'm using for testing is http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/GoogleDevelopers/uploads

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `max-results` url parameter to specify how many videos are returned by the request, however 50 is maximum, so you have to make more than one request if a user has more than 50 videos.

http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Standard_parameters

Answer (score 2):

You can set up the maximum result with:

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/username/uploads?&max-results=50
```

When You make a new request, for the next 50 videos, you can start with an index:

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/username/uploads?&max-results=50&start-index=51
```