# How To get all the youtube video URLS in my channel?

Tags: youtube-api

I have a channel with 500+ videos, and would like a list of all the video URLS within my channel.

I have tried:

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads?key=DEVELOPER_KEY

Developer Key from: https://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard

I simply get:
**User authentication required.
Error 401**

No idea how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/your_youtube_username/uploads?max-results=50&start-index=1&prettyprint=true&fields=entry(title,media:group(media:player(@url)))

Some changes in the Sunxperous code.

max-query for **max-results**

insert **$prettyprint** to see more beautiful

filter the data, will see only titles and URLs.

see more in

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters#max-resultssp

Answer (score 0):

[https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/**your_youtube_username**/uploads?**max-query=50**&**start-index=51**](https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/your_youtube_username/uploads?max-query=50&start-index=51)

Replace `default` with your YouTube username. This GET request does not seem to require a developer key.

[YouTube API v2.0 - API Query Parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters#max-resultssp) describes the use of the `max-query` search parameter. As it will only return a maximum of 50 results, use it with `start-index` to determine the range of the requested results. The sample link above will return upload results of indexes *51* to *100*.

Hence, you will need to make multiple requests in order to fetch all 500+ videos.
[YouTube API - Get All Videos From User limits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019401/youtube-api-get-all-videos-from-user-limits) has a similar question.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I display more than 25 URLs?

Comment: I have expanded my answer.

Comment: Is there a script that can run through the entire video list to extract all 2000+ video URLs ?

Comment: Whichever language you are working in, just loop requests - bearing in mind the `start-index` value - until all URLs have been fetched.

Comment: This method is no longer availble