# How to get all videos uploaded by a specific user via YouTube API

Tags: android, api, youtube, youtube-api

This is a simple question. We need to get all the videos uploaded to our channel in our Android application using YouTube API. According to the YouTube API v2.0 documentation this is a really easy case - https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_feeds#User_Uploaded_Videos.
They say that:

> To ensure that the API response contains the most up-to-date
>   information available for the user's videos, do not use any parameters
>   other than start-index and max-results in your request. Requests using
>   other parameters, such as orderby, will return cached results.

Great! According to the above doc the URL is https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/itcuties/uploads, but the returned result doesn't contain all of our videos. What's going on?
The question is, **how to get all the videos uploaded by a given user using YouTube API?**

Answer (score 0):

Ok, case solved - [YouTube API - Get All Videos From User limits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019401/youtube-api-get-all-videos-from-user-limits) :)

We need to add max-results paramter - https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/itcuties/uploads?max-results=50

Back to coding! Have a nice day!